# Is there a way to avoid double select to check if not exists or value superior to n in an INSERT INTO

Tags: java, sql, postgresql

I would like to know if it's possible to avoid double select in this query to check if not exists at the same time that it checks if superior to X

```java
PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("""
                    INSERT INTO guilds_polls_user_choices (guild_id, poll_id, choice_id, user_id)
                    SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?
                    WHERE (SELECT vote_count FROM guilds_polls_user_vote_count WHERE user_id = ? AND poll_id = ?) < ? OR
                          NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM guilds_polls_user_vote_count WHERE user_id = ? AND poll_id = ?)
                    ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
                    """);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
...
WHERE COALESCE((SELECT vote_count < ? FROM guilds_polls_user_vote_count WHERE user_id = ? AND poll_id = ?), TRUE)
```

see test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DuDMdZdW)

Comment: ```INSERT INTO guilds_polls_user_choices (guild_id, poll_id, choice_id, user_id)
SELECT ?, ?, ?, ?
WHERE COALESCE((SELECT vote_count < ? FROM guilds_polls_user_vote_count WHERE user_id = ? AND poll_id = ?), TRUE)
ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING;
```

Not working :/

Comment: Well, from a sql standpoint, this seems to do the job, see the test in dbfiddle. Then I don't know how to insert that sql statement in your java code to make it working well...

Comment: I test it on DataGrip, without going through my java code